# Visual Studio seems to be caching ARM template components

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to build a nested template in VS using the `resourcegroup()` feature* and on my first attempt I had an old version of the API in my template and when I validated it, it failed (fair enough). I've since updated the value to a supported version `"apiVersion": "2017-05-10"`

But when I validate it fails with:

`The api-version '2016-07-01' used to deploy the template does not support 'ResourceGroup' property. Please use api-version '2017-05-10' or later to deploy the template...`

I'm not using that version of the API! I've checked the `bin\Debug\staging\` files and the `azuredeploy.json` contains the correct API version.

Appears that VS is caching that value from somewhere and failing the validation, any idea where?

I'm using VS 2017 v15.1 (26403.7)

** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-cross-resource-group-deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update Azure Powershell to the latest version and it will work. This is (the api version you see in the error) what the Powershell is using to talk to the API.